# Kafka to take data from web api and write to elastic search

Tags: python, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, vaticle-typedb

Please Note: *I am using Kafka for the first time and do not know much about it's terminologies*

I want to make a data pipeline that read logs from multiple servers. Logs are available through REST APIs.

Currently, To read those logs *i am using python get requests* But as there will be multiple web servers in numbers and it needs to be in real time as some new data can be read from that web server, I am thinking to use Kafka.

Question 1: Can I read data using Kafka that previously i am getting using python get request? 
Question 2: If yes then how? any architecture reference. If not then how can i read using python get request from multiple APIs? 
Question 3: How can I send this data to elasticsearch.
Question 4: Can I send this data directly from Kafka to TypeDB skipping elasticsearch?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> read data using Kafka that previously i am getting using python get request

I don't know what this means. Kafka doesn't use HTTP, so wouldn't be doing/receiving GET requests

> read using python get request from multiple APIs

Use a loop?

```
for api in apis:
    resp = requests.get(api)
```

> that read logs from multiple servers... Logs are available through REST APIs

I think that is a problem. While you can expose logs through an API, it would really be beneficial (assuming you control the API servers) to write the logs *to disk*. Then you can use various log forwarding tools (like Elastic's Filebeat) to forward that data to Kafka and/or Elasticsearch.

> send this data to elasticsearch

Like I said, Filebeat is an option. Otherwise, look into *Kafka Connect* for both Elasticsearch and TypeDB